# Load javascript dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

In my project requirement I need to add java script dynamically 
I have a js file global.js which contains all global variable that I want to add dynamically.
I also want to add global.js before util.js( which uses variable defined in global.js) which is not happening

If I open page source I can't see the global.js added there
I also want this to be work in all browser mainly in ie6 and ie8

my code Index.html

```
<script src="../fw.ui.lib/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.table, sap.ui.ux3"
                  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">

            </script>

            <script src="../fw.ui/js/application_properties.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../fw.ui/js/header.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../fw.ui/js/dao/userDAO.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <!-- add sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3 and/or other libraries to 'data-sap-ui-libs' if required -->
            <script src="js/controls/DynamicJsLoad.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script></script>
            <script>addScriptDynamically()</script>
 <script src="js/controls/util.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

DynamicJsLoad.js

```
function loadScript(url){
      var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[5];
      var d = document.createElement('script');
      d.src = url;
      d.type = 'text/javascript';
      d.async = false;
      d.defer = true;
      e.parentNode.insertBefore(d,e);
}

function addScriptDynamically(){
      var scheme = getCacheBurstScheme();
      if( scheme == 'dev'){
            scheme = new Date();
      }
      loadScript('js/global.js'+'?scheme='+scheme);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a complex way of dynamically loading your dependencies. Why not use RequireJS? http://requirejs.org/

Comment: RequireJS is the perfect library for this task. Your manual implementation seems unnecessarily complex. http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery anyway, you could leverage their [`loadScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function. An example from their website:

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    // [...]
});
```

Regarding your current solution, here are a couple of hints:

1. You set `defer = true`, which will defer loading (and executing) of your dynamically loaded script to the end. Thus after `util.js`. I don't think you want that
2. Dynamically loaded js sources do not appear in your page's source code. You might need to use a tool like Firebug to validate if things have loaded.

Comment: so u are suggesting that the way i am doing will not acheieve what i want (might be there is bug or sth)

Comment: @Arvind: No, I'm suggesting that if you have jQuery as a dependency anyway, you might as well use jQuery for the task. See the updated answer for some hints regarding your own attempt

Comment: Thanks that getScript worked but one more problem in this it is adding one random no in the url i want control on that.. for production i want this to be build no not random always but for dev environment this is fine